# define multiple release years for an album

Tags: itunes, mp3, id3-tag

Is there a way to define multiple release years in the mp3 tags using iTunes? The reason I am asking is that I have a lot of "remastered" albums in my iTunes database that were released in the last couple of years but the original ones had been released much earlier. Now I would like to store the release year of the original album with it. So that for example I would be able to sort and search by original release year OR by acutal release year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, there is no such capability in iTunes. However, the [ID3 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) description on Wikipedia has some information. Basically, what you want is possible, but varies between ID3 tag version.

- In ID3 v2.3:

  - There is a `TORY` tag for the original release year
  - There is a `TYER` tag for the actual release year
- In ID3 v2.4:

  - There is a `TDOR` tag for original release *time*
  - There is a `TDRL` tag for actual release *time*

In effect, v2.4 got more specific with the tags (going from year to time), and any half-decent ID3 tag editor should handle either version of the spec just fine. However, iTunes doesn't handle these tags natively.